# Restoring Android Studio setting

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio was working fine in my PC. I then tried making an new project by including Open CV modules. What I did was to include Open CV libraries by adding them to Import Modules.
After that my previous projects which were opening with no problem seemed to not load properly.

I suspect that the settings from Open CV project is being maintained in those projects also. The PROJECT pane on the left side of Android Studio does not open properly.

I checked the **Project Structure**. In Project SDK, there was <**No SDK**>. I selected Android API 31 platform. But still the project did not load fully.

How can I restore my previous projects ? I am using Windows 10.
Below is how my previous projects look like.

[image: Main Screen]

In the run/Debug configuration below "Android App" is missing
[image: Run Debug Configuration]

This is how it should actually look like
[image]

Comment: What's your platform and OS?

Comment: Did you try to reset Android Studio ?

Comment: I don't see any error in the IDE .. Are u asking about the directory structure ? if yes u can click on project (left top corner) and select Android .

Comment: I clicked in "Add configuration..." button on right side shown in picture.  In Module name it is <no module>. For projects, that are ok, generally it is <projectname.app>